# How to change background color of a div using Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this following line inside the template:

```
    <div class="card" @click="!state.clicked" :style="state.style">
```

And inside the script this code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { ref, computed, reactive } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Card",

  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      clicked: false,
      style: computed(() => {
        backgroundColor: state.clicked ? "red" : "white";
      })
    });

    return {
      state
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

But my color doesn't change. My clicked flag is toggling correctly, but I just can't applied the background color.

Not sure if this is a reactivity issue or just the way I set the background color.

Any ideas ?

Comment: @click="state.clicked=!state.clicked" ?

Comment: There is no change unfortunately

Comment: just copied this into codesandbox ... to make it short computed does not return anything

Comment: Did that worked for you ? I don't see any change for me

Comment: i dont get vue3 runnig - import issues, so not yet XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computed propertie doesnt return anything and returning nothing means it automatically returns undefined. Wrap it in parenthesis

```
  style: computed(() => ({
    backgroundColor: state.clicked ? "red" : "white"
  }))
```